# lighting from a 12v lead acid battery

Tags: power, distance

i want to hook up upto 5 lighting bulbs, 12watt each from a 12v battery. These lighting bulbs will be feed directly from a 12v battery without any inverter etc.
The main question is that for a 100 yards or about 300 feet distance
 what gauge wire should I use to avoid extra waste/loss of power from the battery.
Thanks

Comment: *to avoid extra waste/loss of power from the battery* You will **always** have losses unless you use superconducting wires. Transporting 60 W at 12 V over 100 meter (we're engineers here, we use SI standards not weird units) is asking too much. Rough estimate: even with ridiculously thick cable you could easily lose 20% of the power, the bulbs would not burn at full brightness either.

Comment: Go here: http://www.calculator.net/voltage-drop-calculator.html and calculate the losses.

Comment: It will be well worth your trouble to carry the battery over to where you want the lights. You can walk 100 yards and save $200 on cable. Any time you need to move electricity over a long distance, the higher the voltage the better, from a cost perspective.

Comment: I just made up that number. $200. The point is, copper is expensive, and 12V circuits need a lot of it.

Comment: @FakeMoustache 'ere, don't go dissing our weird units or you'll find yourself 1 fathom deep in the 40 acre field a chain's length from the mile marker.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on voltage drop you want to allow.
Your total current draw is 5A.
Distance is 2x 90m.
This is table of AWG wire sizes: [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_wire_gauge#Tables_of_AWG_wire_sizes)

If you use AWG10, which has resistance 0.003 ohm/m, voltage drop is ~3V.
If you use AWG5, which has resistance 0.001 ohm/m, voltage drop is ~1V.

So, you have to decide what voltage drop you will allow and calculate wire gauge.

**UPDATE:**
You have to calculate with double distance. There are actually 2 wires, one from battery to bulbs and one from bulbs to battery. Both of these wires have that mentioned voltage drop. Thanks to mkeith for pointing it out.

Comment: Use the round-trip length. 180m * 0.003 = 0.54 Ohms. 0.54 * 5A = 2.7V.

Comment: You are right, thanks for your comment. I absolutely forgot about that return path :)

Answer (score 1):

Each lamp will draw about 1 A that is 5 A in total.  The volt drop and losses for 5 A with metric 200 m Cu cable are as follows:

$$1,5~mm^2 -> 25~V/A/km -> 25~W\\
 2,5~mm^2 -> 15~V/A/km -> 15~W\\
 4~mm^2 -> 10~V/A/km -> 10~W\\
 6~mm^2 -> 6~V/A/km -> 6~W\\
 10~mm^2 -> 4~V/A/km -> 4~W\\
 16~mm^2 -> 2~V/A/km -> 2~W\\
 25~mm^2 -> 1,5~V/A/km -> 1,5~W\\
$$

You can decide how much you want to spend on cable.

Answer (score 1):

> distance:300ft, load current: 5A

choose a cable that can conduct in multiple of this current twice or trice would be better considering thrice 3 * 5 approximately 15 Amps

Since the cable carry DC and need to have low loss, not considering the cost of cable you can choose SWG 1/2 which offer low resistance per feet [SWG reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_wire_gauge#Tables_of_AWG_wire_sizes)